# laravel date after posting comment

Tags: php, laravel

I’m creating a forum script in laravel and I made it pretty far. Now what I’m trying to achieve is when person posts a comment in a thread I want to make it possible for him to edit that comment but that the option for edit is only available for 5 minutes after posting it when 5 minutes pass the option for edit is gone.

For example thread is created at

2017-05-17 09:40:01

And it’s available to edit until

2017-05-17 09:45:01

How can I create that in this loop ?

created_at is the row in the table that displays when the comment is posted

```
@forelse($thread->comments as $comment)

    <div class="comment-list well well-lg">
        <p>Comment posted by {{$comment->user->name}}</p>

        <p>{{$comment->body}}</p>

        @if(auth()->user()->id == $comment->user_id)
            <a href="{{route('thread.edit',$thread->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</a>
        @endif

    </div>

    @empty
        <p> - No comments here.</p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@if((auth()->user()->id == $comment->user_id) && (abs(time() - strtotime($comment->created_at)) < 300))
```

(current timestamp - timestamp of creating comment have to be less than 300 seconds)